# Is there a way for non-moderators to list pending edits?

Tags: support, editing, review

With Parenting.SE still in its infancy, we have only one user able to approve tag wiki edits, and only two able to approve question/answer edits.  Because neither of us has the 2,000 rep needed to use moderator tools (such as the list of pending edits), we only see pending edits if we happen across the tag wiki page or question/answer in our normal reading.

Is there any way for us to see a list of pending edits, so we can help things on the site move along smoothly without relying on site-wide mods to pick up the slack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's even worse than you think, the reputation needed for the ability to see a list of pending edits is not reduced on beta sites, it is still at 10.000 ([confirmed by Rebecca Chernoff in this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82746/no-access-to-suggested-edits-review-on-skeptics-se)). If that is not changed, you will depend on your pro-temp mods, as soon as you get them, to approve the overlooked pending edits.

On Skeptics some of the prolific editors just pinged the users that could approve edits in chat and posted the links so that someone could approve them.

Comment: What a pain! It's not much use to be able to approve edits if you can't *find* the edits.

Comment: @HedgeMage and Fabian, as a result of the linked question, this was changed and is now linked to the mod tools privilege (which is already reduced during beta).